# Como puedo agregar una restricción check al campo de una tabla en MySql

Tags: mysql

Como puedo agregar una restricción check a la tabla (clientesCopy por ejemplo) en el campo cédula, para que solo permita valores de 11 caracteres de longitud.

Tengo esta sintaxis pero no me funciona:

```
create table clientesCopy 
(cedula int(11) not null, nombre varchar(50) not null, apellido varchar(50) not null, primary key (cedula))
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

La tabla clientesCopy la he creado nueva no tiene registros cargados, esta es su estructura:

```
CREATE TABLE clientescopy 
(ClienteID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
Nombre varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
Apellido varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
Cedula varchar(11) NOT NULL, 
Teléfono varchar(13) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (ClienteID) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Tabla de Clientes de la BD' –
```

Comment: Nos muestras por favor lo que hayas intentado al momento?

Comment: Para este tipo de preguntas, recuerda incluir la definición de la tabla y lo que intentaste para resolver tu problema. **Como texto**

Comment: Tengo esta Sintaxis:                                                                                  
create table clientesCopy (
cedula int(11) not null,
nombre varchar(50) not null,
apellido varchar(50) not null,
primary key (cedula))ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: La tabla clientesCopy la he creado nueva no tiene registros cargados, le envió el query que genera el MySql:                                                     
   CREATE TABLE `clientescopy` (
  `ClienteID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Apellido` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Cedula` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `Teléfono` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClienteID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Tabla de Clientes de la BD'

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y pone toda la informacion dentro de la pregunta

Comment: Listo ya lo coloque.

Comment: Pero con colocar `columna INT(11)` por ejemplo ya debería tener establecida la longitud máxima que podrá recibir dicha columna

Comment: Gracias, sin embargo no comprendo bien este parte de echo me surgen preguntas como  si esto de puede Deshabilitar, Habilitar y listar las restricciones que tiene la tabla por medio de algun query.

Comment: Entonces @maikervasquez deberías por favor indicar de manera clara lo que deseas lograr, pues como te comento si lo que deseas es indicar que solo acepte hasta un máximo de 20 caracteres con lo anterior debe alcanzar, pero ya cuando nos dices deshabilitar ya no queda claro lo que buscas conseguir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé qué versión estás usando de MySQL, pero ya desde hace un rato que tiene un modo [STRICT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict) en el que, si intentas insertar una cadena de longitud mayor a la permitida por el campo (digamos, **11** para la **cédula**), te va a arrojar un error

> ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'xxx' at row 1

Ahora, si quieres probar un constraint `CHECK`, sólo está disponible desde la versión [8.0.16](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html); antes de eso el motor simplemente lo ignora sin más (pura calidad, eh?)

Sin embargo, esa expresión suele tener más utilidad cuando valida, por ejemplo, rangos para los valores (p.ej. valores enteros)

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
  CHECK (c1 <> c2),
  c1 INT CHECK (c1 > 10),
  c2 INT CONSTRAINT c2_positive CHECK (c2 > 0),
  c3 INT CHECK (c3 < 100),
  CONSTRAINT c1_nonzero CHECK (c1 <> 0),
  CHECK (c1 > c3)
);
```

Entonces, no parecería que un `constraint` `CHECK` sea lo que buscas para resolver el problema de limitar la longitud de un `varchar`.

Referencia en SO en inglés: [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459184/mysql-too-long-varchar-truncation-error-setting)

Comment: Jajaja, están la mar de divertidos los -1 a la 1am

Comment: Gracias estimado y disculpa la hora, en unas horas retomare el caso.

Comment: ¿Qué utilidad tendría una restricción `CHECK` en este caso, cuando la longitud del campo se puede definir en el mismo campo con `TIPO(N)` donde `TIPO` es el tipo de dato y `N` es la longitud del mismo?

Comment: Efectivamente tienes razón ya lo comprendo.